# Rails - mail_form send to contact_email:string in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, mail-form

I am using mail_form with simple_form. I have a "job"-model with a string field called "contact_email". The contact_email is different for every "job". I am trying to have a form which sends to that specific email but I need help to figure out how to do it.

This is what I have so far:

**app/routes.rb**

```
resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

**models/contact.rb**

```
attribute :name,      :validate => true
attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+ ([\w]{2,})\z/i
attribute :message
attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

def headers
 {
   :subject => "Contact",
   :to => "email@example.com",
   :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
  }
end
```

**controllers/contacts.rb**

```
def new
 @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
 @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
 @contact.request = request
 if @contact.deliver
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
 else
  flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
  render :new
 end
end
```

**views/contacts/_new.html.erb**

```
<div align="center">
 <h3>Send A message to Us</h3>
 <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
  <div class= "hidden">
   <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
  </div>
  <div>
  </br>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**views/contacts/create.html.erb**

```
<div>
 <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div>
   <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**views/jobs/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'contacts/new' %>
```

So, instead of `:to => "email@example.com"` I want the email to be sent to job.contact_email (a string in my jobs model).

Comment: Try changing `:to => "email@example.com"` `:to => "#{contact_email}"`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, unfortunately it didn't work. I think the problem is that my model/contact.rb has no idea of what contact_email is. Thats the bit I need help with.

Comment: where is your jobs model?

Comment: There is no mention of the mailer in my jobs model, it only consists of some validations and "belongs to"-references.